# Update Column Names Using Data Dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column names 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  I can easily assign the field names when I load the data but the issue becomes if the column name changes, I would not know.  There is another file where the column names 0, 1, 2, 3 are identified along with their description.  0 is ID Number, 1, is Title, etc.

I did convert the dataframe to a dictionary.

```
    layout_dict = layout_df.to_dict('records')
    
    [{'FIELD_NUMBER': '0',
    'FIELD_DESCRIPTION': 'ID Number',
    'FIELD_TYPE': 'String',
    'COMMENTS': 'SURE Voter ID number'},
    {'FIELD_NUMBER': '1',
    'FIELD_DESCRIPTION': 'Title',
    'FIELD_TYPE': 'String',
    'COMMENTS': nan},
```

From the layout_df dataframe with the column names 0, 1, 2, 3 is there a way to programmatically assign the column names to the FIELD_NUMBER in the dictionary and pull the FIELD_DESCRIPTION into the column name.

Here is how the data appears in the norco_df dataframe

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | dr |
| 234 | mr |

Once the mapping occurs to the data dictionary, the column names in norco_df dataframe should be renamed to:

| ID Number | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | dr |
| 234 | mr |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that field numbers are string in layout_dict. The following list comprehension converts the column names

```
norco_df.columns = [item['FIELD_DESCRIPTION'] for old_col in norco_df.columns for item in layout_dict if item['FIELD_NUMBER'] == str(old_col)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of the same shape as what `.rename()` takes from your `layout_df`:

```
columns = layout_df.set_index('FIELD_NUMBER')['FIELD_DESCRIPTION'].to_dict()
norco_df = norco_df.rename(columns=columns)
print(norco_df)
```

Output:

```
   ID Number Title
0        123    dr
1        234    mr
```

Comment: If I understood correctly OPs  constraints, this shouldn't work: "*but the issue becomes if the column name changes*". It seems the replacement should be positional.

Comment: I believe that "I can easily assign the field names when I load the data" refers to something like `.read_csv(..., names=["ID Number","Title"])` (hardcoded). But that does beg the question, why not just set `names=layout_df['FIELD_DESCRIPTION']` after sorting by `FIELD_NUMBER` if necessary~

Answer (score 0):

Use the `layout_df` DataFrame to set up a Series and `reindex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'), index=[0])

s = layout_df.astype({'FIELD_NUMBER': int}).set_index('FIELD_NUMBER')['FIELD_DESCRIPTION']
df.columns = s.reindex(range(df.shape[1])).to_list()
```

Output:

```
  ID Number Title  NaN
0       NaN   NaN  NaN
```